# Flutter hide navigation bar through check list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, dart-pub

I'm really new to flutter but is it possible to hide the (appbar) navigation bar through the checkbox programmatically?

Comment: Share your code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Use a bool variable for eg: `showAppBar` and use like this

```dart
Scaffold(
      appBar:showAppBar? AppBar():null,
)
```

Comment: Found answer? Accept the answer, will be usefull for others